# Is there a command or a way to clear workspace and command window at the same time?

Tags: matlab, workspace, command-window

I feel a little troublesome to enter the `clear` command to clear the workspace, and then enter the `clc` command to clear the command window.

Is there a command or a way to clear the workspace and the command window at the same time?

Comment: I feel like questions like this should be included as exercises in MathWorks documentation, training or Cody.  It's a good example of thinking about how to do things within Matlab.  Especially when it comes to customizing Matlab with `startup.m` and `finish.m`.

Comment: @Matt Yes, I agree. It will make the MATLAB documentation better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is not a built-in function to do both of these things at once.

Thankfully you can easily script this behavior by creating a script on your path that calls the commands that you want. For example, you could name your script `clr.m` and give it the following contents

**`clr.m`**

```
clear all;
clc;
```

If your intention is to completely clear everything, something like [`nuke`](https://github.com/suever/nuke/blob/master/nuke.m) (disclaimer: I am the developer) may be better suited to your needs as it is more complete.

Comment: Thanks for the quick and detailed answer. I think it is the best answer by far. Although I've just found creating a command shortcut can do this thing, creating a script should be quicker since I use keyboard more than using a mouse when testing and coding. ^_^

Comment: Just a note: `clear all` is usually overkill and unwarranted. People mostly want to just clear variables out of their RAM, which'd be `clear` (short for `clear vars`). `clear all` also removed pre-(temporarily)compiled functions, so calling those again would slow the computation, as it will be JITted again.

Comment: @Adriaan, Thanks for the follow-up. Now I got it and will use "clear". ^_^

Comment: And I found another way to clear the Command Window by using the command **home**, that "**clears**" the window and moves the cursor to the upper-left corner of the window, but does not empty the scroll buffer like the command **clc**. Thus, after using the command **home**, the "cleared" commands can still be searched out in the **Find** dialog of the Command Window. See [here](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_env/find-text-in-command-window-or-history.html) for details.